# Spring TransactionInterceptor with multiple TransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

In a webapplication I am using different components which are all using Spring 3.0.x having their own `DataSource` and `TransactionManager` (all with different names). They are all included in the context via the "main" webapp via including their spring config.

```
<import resource="classpath:spring-config-componentName.xml" />
```

In each of the Spring configs of the components I am using declarative transaction management, enabled via

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager_componentName" />
```

And for each method that should be transactional I add a annotation that looks like this:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, value="transactionManager_componentName")
```

The problem I have is that I found out that only one `TransactionInterceptor` is created which has a reference to one of the transactionManagers but not of the one of the component itself. Is there a way to handle this? Like to specify a `TransactionInterceptor` as a bean and then reference it in the `@Transactional` annotation?

I think there is a possibility by specifying a `TransactionProxyFactoryBean` in each component and doing the declarative transaciton management via the xml config. But this is something I would like to avoid.

The proposed way as described in the Spring docs ([10.5.6.2 Multiple Transaction Managers with @Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional)) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out what the problem was and I have to say that it works as it is described in the spring docs.
If you are using more than one `TransactionManager`in your Spring Container and you are using `@Transaction`it does **not** work if you are specifiying the `TransactionManager` like this:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager_componentName" />
```

All you have to do ist to remove the specification of the `TransactionManager` and use a configuration like this:

```
<!-- ========== ENABLE ANNOTATIONS  ========== -->

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<!-- ========== TRANSACTION MANAGER ========== -->

<bean id="transactionManager_component1"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource_component1" />
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
    <qualifier value="component1"/>
</bean>
```

And for you methods you want to run in a transaction then just specify it like this:

```
@Transactional(value="component1")
```